# LWC data shows in console, but for:each fails to display it

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I'm simply trying to display a list of queried Activities here records. Next, I'll add checkboxes to each.

See screenshot here: the Activities card should display the 6 records as seen in the console. I've been at this for several hours. I was able to render same records with lightning datatable, but it doesn't have the look and feel I want (I do like datatable's built-in checkboxes, but I figure I can use slds-checkbox-button or slds-checkbox for that).

[image]

Here's my current code

---

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="Activities" icon-name="custom:custom14">
    <ul class="slds-m-around_medium">
      <template for:each={wiredActivities.data} for:item="activity">
          <li key={activity.Id}>
              {activity.Title__c}
          </li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

---

```
import {LightningElement, wire} from 'lwc';
import getAllEventActivities from '@salesforce/apex/EventActivities_Ctrl.getAllEventActivities';
export default class EventActivityChecklist extends LightningElement {
  
  @wire (getAllEventActivities) wiredActivities ({data,error}){
    if (data) {
      console.log(data);
    } else if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
public with sharing class EventActivities_Ctrl {

    @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static List<Event_Activity__c> getAllEventActivities() {
      return [SELECT id, Title__c, Type__c 
              FROM Event_Activity__c 
              ORDER BY Type__c ASC];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a list of records!
[image]

Caspar and CyberJus were right about a lot here. What was preventing their suggestions from working was the li markup I was using. Below, you'll see I changed to span and div. HTML nerds, please explain why ul and li didn't work here; it seems it should have.

In the JS file, you'll see I now declare
activities = [];
Then, I assign data to it.

I believe there's a few ways mentioned in Caspar's and CyberJus' posts that would work, now that I got the HTML working.

---

```
    <template>
      <lightning-card title="Activities" icon-name="custom:custom14">
        <ul class="slds-m-around_medium">
          <template for:each={activities} for:item="ac">
            <span key={ac.id}>
              <div class="slds-col">
                   <lightning-input type="checkbox" label={ac.Title__c} ></lightning-input>
              </div>
            </span>
          </template>
        </ul>
      </lightning-card>
    </template>
```

---

```
import {LightningElement, wire} from 'lwc';
import getAllEventActivities from '@salesforce/apex/EventActivities_Ctrl.getAllEventActivities';

export default class EventActivityChecklist extends LightningElement {
  
  activities = [];
  @wire(getAllEventActivities) getAllEventActivitiesHandler({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
      this.activities = data;
      console.log(data);
    } else if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
public with sharing class EventActivities_Ctrl {

    @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static List<Event_Activity__c> getAllEventActivities() {
      return [SELECT id, Title__c, Type__c 
              FROM Event_Activity__c 
              ORDER BY Type__c ASC];
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the direct property `wire` technique with the `method` version.

Because you have a method, you need to explicitly store the `data` somewhere - in the example below, I'm setting it to `activities`

Then you just need to reference in the iterator in the template.

eg:

```
<template for:each={activities} for:item="activity">
```

code:

```
activities = [];
 @wire(getAllEventActivities)
 getAllEventActivitiesHandler({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
      this.activities = data;
    } else if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: When I remove .data as you suggest, nothing renders (not even the Card Title as before) and I get the following error: LC {component: "markup://c:eventActivityChecklist", componentStack: "[flexipageEditor:node] > [flexipage:recordHomeTemp… > [aura:expression] > [c:eventActivityChecklist]", action: null, name: "TypeError", message: "Error during LWC component connect phase: [e[jr] is not a function]", …}

Comment: Thanks for your help Caspar. I'm not understanding your last comment here. My original syntax failed.

Comment: Following gives an Unexpected token error.  let activities = [];

Comment: Fixed - sorry. no `let` in the class body!

Comment: Thanks Caspar. Unfortunately, after removing "let" from the array variable, same result: Card Title appears but no records show.

Comment: can you update your question above with the current code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use @wire in two ways, to a property or a function. You are wiring to a function, not a property.

If you want to use wiredActivities.data you have to use the single variable name as property

```
@wire (getAllEventActivities) 
   wiredActivities;
```

This way you have it is returning to a function wiredActivities. In this case you havent set any variable the view can use to display the results, you are only using it in the console.log

```
@wire (getAllEventActivities) 
  wiredActivities ({data,error}){
    if (data) {
      console.log(data);
    } else if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

}

To use it the way you have set data to something in your method and then use that in your view.

Comment: When I use the following, as you suggest, I get same result: it shows the Card Title but no records:  @wire (getAllEventActivities) wiredActivities;

Comment: Per your second suggestion... I just tried  this but got same result: Card Title but no records.

@track activityList;

 if (data) {
      this.activityList = data;
      console.log(data);
...

In the html: for:each={activityList}

Answer (score 1):

It's helpful to look through [Understand the Wire Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about). You can return the results to a [property](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/apexWireMethodToProperty) or [function](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/apexWireMethodToFunction) as CyberJus highlighted and shown in those lwc-recipes linked. Depending on which you do, changes what you reference in your `for:each`. The following is from the doc and explains what is returned

> A private property or function that receives the stream of data from
> the wire service. **If a property** is decorated with @wire, the results
> are returned to the property’s data property or error property. **If a
> function** is decorated with @wire, the results are returned in an
> object with a data property and an error property.

If you return the results to a **function**, then you're passed an object (with `data` and `errors` properties) into your function to handle/execute your logic. You're currently doing this (returning your activities to a function), but your function is not doing anything with `data` other than `console.log` so there's no variable that has your list of activities. You need to store the provided information into a variable to reference in your html.

```
allActivities = [];

@wire (getAllEventActivities) wiredActivities ({data,error}){
    if (data) {
      allActivities = data; //store the returned information in this function
    } else if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Once you've provided your array of events to a variable, you simply reference it in the `for:each`

```
<template for:each={allActivities} for:item="activity">
```

---

If you decide you want to return the results to a **Property**

```
@wire (getAllEventActivities) 
   wiredActivities;
```

The result is provided to the property (`wiredActivities`). The information is within `data` as you're getting it as Salesforce returned it (within the `data` and `error`). So, in your html, you need to reference/loop through `data` within your property (in this case, your list of events)

```
<template for:each={wiredActivities.data} for:item="activity">
```